# RxJS forkJoin does not complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

When I subscribe to getAllSubModules forkJoin executes all those observables without error but does not complete. I know forkJoin completes only after all its observables completed but as a proof I see '-----' 3 times in console which confirm everything is successful so all its observables completed.

```
 getSubmodules(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.authService.getToken()
      .flatMap((token) => this.http.get(`${this.URL}/ROS/applications/modules/${id}/subModules?token=${token}`))
      .map((res: any) => res.data.map((subModule) => this.mapSubModules(subModule)));
  }
  getAllSubmodules(): Observable<any> {
    const tasks = [];
    this.modules.forEach((module: AppModule) => {
      const obs = this.getSubmodules(module.id).map((subModules) => {
        this.allSubModules[module.id] = subModules;
        console.log('--------------------');
      });
      tasks.push(obs);
    });
    return Observable.forkJoin(...tasks).retry(2);
  }
  mapSubModules(moduleData) {
    if (moduleData.id) {
      const subModule = <SubModule> {
        id: moduleData.id,
        parentId: moduleData.parentId,
        typeId: moduleData.typeId,
        name: moduleData.name.az,
        active: true
      };
      return subModule;
    }
  }
```

This code is not executed when using **forkJoin**:

```
 this.universityService.getAllSubmodules().subscribe(() => {             
        // --- Below is not executed!--
        console.log('subModules in Report Co');
        console.log(this.universityService.allSubModules);
        this.checkUrl();
        this.showChild = true;
      }, (er) => console.log(er));
```

but when I use **combineLatest** instead of forkJoin it works as expected.
 So what is problem?Hope someone give advice.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here: map calls with no return, lack of types, ambiguous definition of mapSubmodules method (return type void or SubModule).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expectation is incorrect. Having `console.log('--------------------')` emitted 3 times only means that you have received 3 `onNext` events. `forkJoin` waits for all observables to complete.

Try what happens if you look at the individual streams with `.do(next=>{},err=>{},complete => console.log('completed'))` or explicitly define when your streams should complete using `.take(1)` and/or `.timeout(1000)`.

Does `authService..getToken()` complete after emitting one value?

Comment: Thanks so much .Adding take(1) solved the problem. It was because authService.getToken() did not complete.just emitted next. I appreciate for your help!