# How to return value from subscribe of forkJoin with angular 6 and RxJs 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

```
private save(payload) {

  const newMedias: Observable<Media>[] = [];
  const newMediaInStepIndex: number[] = [];

  (payload.formData.steps).forEach((step: Step, stepIndex: number) => {
    const media: Observable<Media> = this.createOneMedia(step);
    if (media !== undefined) {
      newMedias.push(media);
      newMediaInStepIndex.push(stepIndex);
    }
  });

  forkJoin(newMedias).subscribe(medias => {
    medias.forEach((media, i) => {
      console.log('Media created with id: ' + media.id + ' in step ' + newMediaInStepIndex[i]);
      payload.formData.steps[newMediaInStepIndex[i]].media[0].id  = media.id;
    });
  });

  return this.createRecipe(payload);
}
```

My problem is that the following line is executed asynchronously and therefore not before the return of the end:

```
payload.formData.steps[newMediaInStepIndex[i]].media[0].id  = media.id;
```

so I need to do the return of the end once the end of the subscribe. I think we have to cut this function in half.

**IMPORTANT: return in save(payload)**

Comment: Similar question `https://stackoverflow.com/q/48879798/1876572`

Comment: @Eldho, is not return on `save(isNew)` in this exemple. that's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it end of my solution:

```
private save(p): Observable<Action> {

    const payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p));

    const newMedias: Observable<Media>[] = [];
    const newMediaInStepIndex: number[] = [];

    (payload.formData.steps).forEach((step: Step, stepIndex: number) => {
        const media: Observable<Media> = this.createOneMedia(step);
        if (media !== undefined) {
          newMedias.push(media);
          newMediaInStepIndex.push(stepIndex);
        }
    });

    if (newMedias.length > 0) {
        return forkJoin(newMedias).pipe(mergeMap( (medias) => {
          medias.forEach((media, i) => {
            payload.formData.steps[newMediaInStepIndex[i]].media[0].id = media.id;
          });
          return this.createRecipe(payload);
        }));
    } else {
        return this.createRecipe(payload);
    }

}
```

I change `subscribe` by `mergeMap` in a `pipe`. I return a `Observable<Action>` in the return of my `forkJoin` and return this at the end of `save(p)`.

I add this: `const payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p));` because p comes from `@ngrx`.

Comment: Good solution! In my case, "mergeMap" method didn't work, and "map" helped.

Answer (score 2):

The subscribe method has 3 parameter functions.

1) `next()`, which you have used
2) `error()`, which you haven't
3) `complete()`, which is run once the stream is complete.

So you can add your createRecipe in the complete callback like this:

```
forkJoin(newMedias).subscribe(medias => {
    medias.forEach((media, i) => {
      console.log('Media created with id: ' + media.id + ' in step ' + newMediaInStepIndex[i]);
      payload.formData.steps[newMediaInStepIndex[i]].media[0].id  = media.id;
    });
  },
err => {},
() => {
    this.createRecipe(payload);
});
```

This will call the createRecipe method when all the payloads are loaded (Once all observables in the newMedias array have been resolved).

Hope this helps.

Comment: if `newMedias` is empty `this.createRecipe(payload);` never call

Comment: That is because the subscribe itself is never called. You should do a forkJoin only if newMedias is not empty. Otherwise call createRecipe directly

Comment: thank you, your solution is good. I just have a last problem with the `media.id` setter.  ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property id, object is not extensible

Comment: You need to clone the payload object into a new object and assign it there. Internally there is a preventExtensions being called on the payload object. Read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022130/1504265

Comment: I try `const p = Object.assign({ }, payload);` but do not work

Comment: Where is the return of `save(payload)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Need a function to return the observables that combine from `forkjoin` and then subscribe it from somewhere else

```
private saveToServer(payload) {

  (payload.formData.steps).forEach((step: Step, stepIndex: number) => {
    const media: Observable<Media> = this.createOneMedia(step);
    if (media !== undefined) {
      newMedias.push(media);
      newMediaInStepIndex.push(stepIndex);
    }
  });

  return forkJoin(newMedias) 
}


private save(payload) { 

  this.saveToServer(payload).subscribe(medias => {
    medias.forEach((media, i) => {
      console.log('Media created with id: ' + media.id + ' in step ' + newMediaInStepIndex[i]);
      payload.formData.steps[newMediaInStepIndex[i]].media[0].id  = media.id;

      //call it here
      this.createRecipe(payload);
    });
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Your code will end up calling createRecipe for each observable. The OP wants to run createRecipe after all payloads have been received.

Comment: ForkJoin only get subscribe once all the request has been resolved.

Comment: Tried to look for a example for you. Hopefully this answer shows that https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944184/1504265

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450639/rxjs-forkjoin-does-not-complete this as well

Comment: read the answers carefully.  `forkJoin waits for all observables to complete.`

Comment: Where is the return of `save(payload)` ?